# assign numbers to windows and use those to switch between them (gnome)

Tags: gnome, metacity

My workspace is very simple, just 4 windows (I have a dual display desktop), so I always have all my windows visible. What I would like to do is switch between them just using something like Windows+N where N is a number, so using Windows+1 would take me to the first window starting from the left and so on. Is this possible using gnome?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do this with xbindkeys. Check out https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KeyboardShortcuts for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If the windows have predictable names, then `xwit -names <text>` will pop up any windows with a name starting with "text". You should be able to either run that directly as the action for the keybinding, or save it in an executable shell script, to be run when the keybinding is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

I made an Open-Source tool that might fit your needs :
https://github.com/xurei/hyperkeys

You can assign a shortcut to your window and get the focus by pressing it.
You can either assign a shortcut to a window name (e.g. my password manager is ALT+P), or pin a window to a shortcut on-the-fly (e.g. ALT+SHIFT+Q to pin the currently focused window, and ALT+Q to get the focus of this window).

Hope it helps you :-)